# Boost adjacency_list help needed

Tags: c++, boost, adjacency-list

I'm trying to use Boost's adjacency_list type and I'm having trouble understanding the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html).

Say I define a class named State and I instantiate one instance for each state in the USA:

```
class State { ... };
State california, oregon, nevada, arizona, hawaii, ...
```

I want to enter these into a boost::adjacency_list the vertices are states and the edges are borders. For the states I listed above, I think the graph would have this data:

```
california : oregon, nevada, arizona
hawaii :
oregon : california, nevada
nevada : oregon, california, arizona
arizona : california, nevada
```

I understand how to put ints into the graph and I considered just making an array of states and inserting their array index into the graph, but it seems like I should be able to just say:

```
add_edge(california, oregon, graph);
```

but of course that doesn't work. Please help!

**Edit:**
[Here's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) an example of almost exactly what I need.

Comment: How does that not work, an error would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading up on boost::adjacency_list, it appears you are supposed to use properties for the vertices rather than something like a class:

```
struct VertexProperties {
    std::string stateName;
};

typedef adjacency_list<listS, listS, bidirectionalS, VertexProperties> Graph;
Graph adjacentStates(50);

property_map<Graph, std::string VertexProperties::*>::type
    stateName = get(&VertexProperties::stateName, adjacentStates);

add_edge(vertex("california", adjacentStates), vertex("oregon", adjacentStates), adjacentStates);
```

(Poorly) adapted from [an example in boost](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#f_oXlvyBouA/boost_1_32_0/libs/graph/example/adjacency_list.cpp&q=adjacency_list).

Comment: Oy! It's worse than I thought. I think I'll find a different way to do this. I'd don't want to have to maintain code that... clever. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please add VertexProperties as Graph's 4th template parameter. That means you'll have to add bidirectionalS as 3rd.